# Kafka Streams Internal Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have disabled automatic Topic creation on cluster level. We did not have the need for Kafka streams then. Now that we want to use Kafka streams. We realise that we need to enable auto topic creation for Kafka streams to work properly.What the workaround for Kafka streams to work without enabling Automatic Topic creation

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams wraps AdminClient, so it'll automatically + programmatically create the topics it needs without you having to do anything else.

Comment: I agree. But my question has not been answered. What the work around without enabling Auto topic creation. We disabled auto topic creation for security reasons.

Comment: Your question is answered... You do not need to enable auto topic creation on the broker since AdminClient API is used. That's the same methods that `kafka-topics.sh` uses that you're probably already using to create topics

Comment: Currenly its not working because Auto Topic creation is disabled. Hence my question if there is a work around. Anytime we update Kafkstreams code and restart the application Kafka streams want to create internal topics to do some processing. Meanwhile, users get access denied because Auto Topic creation is disabled. Hence going back to my work aroud solution

Comment: i mean our Kafka streams Application is not working due to the fact that auto topic creation is disabled. We have to manually create the Topics required. We want a workout around where we dont need to create topics manually and also still disable Auto Topic creation

Comment: What is the error it is failing with? I've used Kafka Steams and maintained a cluster with topic creation disabled and it worked absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

Add the required permissions for the user/service-account you are using in streaming application for topic creation/deletion etc. using the tools used by your platform team or kafka-acls command (Command Reference)

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --add --cluster --operation Create  --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181  --allow-principal User:service-account
```